# Facebook and Dynamic URLs

Tags: facebook, wordpress, url, comments

been having real issue with using comments and like buttons on pages like http://staging.bangstyle.com/haircut-detail/?uid=2139&img_id=15231

Facebook doesn't like the "?"

Is there a way to force the url on Facebook? I tried using HTTP URI to get the url but still the url shared on facebook stops at /haircut-detail/

Should i invest time on creating htaccess for these files or a different way that i havent tried. Permalinks and php http uri don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has no problem using "?" in the URL.

I tried your url in the Facebook debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.bangstyle.com%2Fhaircut-detail%2F%3Fuid%3D2139%26img_id%3D15231 it works but is picking up an issue with your head and/or meta tags

> You have  tags ouside of your . This is either because
>   your  was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or
>   you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either
>   way you need to fix it before the tags are usable.

Comment: The issue is when I load that page on lightbox, the like button doesn't parse the whole URL. If I go to the page outside lightbox functionality and I press like, it's working.